# How is my program still running after uninstalling python packages?

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation, python-packaging

I have somewhat of a trivial question but I was wondering how python packages are uninstalled. I'm currently working on an AI agent to play chess and I was playing around with the program. I uninstalled the chess package on my machine using

```
pip uninstall chess
```

[image]

The image above confirms that I have the package uninstalled.
However when I run:

```
import chess
print('hello world')
```

the program still runs fine.
Should I not be seeing some sort of error saying that module could not be found or is there some way that pip uninstalls the package so that it is still on my machine but it is simply just deallocated space that another program can use later.

Comment: There are many possibilities.  Most Macs have multiple Python installations: the system Python 2, the system Python 3, a HomeBrew Python 3, sometimes a VSCode Python 3, etc.  You may have local packages as well as system packages.  Perhaps your `pip3` is a different intallation.  Try `print(chess.__file__)` to see where this one lives.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the __pycache__ folder is holding a reference to it. I'm not sure if that is even possible, but it's the best I've got regarding guesses.

Comment: Make sure the attempt at `import chess` is running in python3 since you used pip3.

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 uninstall chess`.